# angular ng-repeat and adding new element to the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a `ng-repeat` that loops over an array of comments:

```
<li ng-repeat="comment in ad.comments | limitTo:quantity| orderBy : sortComment : true">
        {{comment.uid}}
        <strong style="display: inline;">{{comment.title}}</strong>  {{comment.posted| date}}
        <p readMore> {{comment.text|truncate: textLength }}
          <a ng-show="comment.text.length>25" ng-click="changeLength(textLength)" class="color3"><strong id="moreLessButton">{{moreLessText}}</strong></a>
        </p>
      </li>
```

the `comments` array are from `$http` call, my question is: what is t this array he right way to trigger the `ng-repeat` loop after a user added a new comment? adding a `$watch` to the comments array does not work.
Also pushing a new comment:

```
$scope.ad.comments.push((addDataToCurrntCommentList));
```

do not cause the loop to start again.
I don't want to recall the service to retrieve all comments again.
Adding a new comments is by a angular `modal` the scope son of the parent the is the controller for the `ng-repeat` loop.
Here is the code that surround an adding request `HTML`:

```
<form  id="commentsForm" name="commentsForm" ng-submit="submitComment($event)">
    <i class="fa fa-star " ng-click="alertStar(1)"  id="1"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star " ng-click="alertStar(2)"  id="2"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star " ng-click="alertStar(3)"  id="3"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star " ng-click="alertStar(4)"  id="4"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star " ng-click="alertStar(5)"  id="5"></i>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>{{AdDetailsWords.commentPostTitleLng[languageServ.current]}}</legend>
            <label class="control-label">{{AdDetailsWords.commentTitleLng[languageServ.current]}}*</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" cols="3" rows="1"  id="commentTitle-textarea" tabindex="1"  ng-model="commentTitle" required ></textarea>
            <div class="control-field">
                <label  class="control-label">{{AdDetailsWords.commentTextLng[languageServ.current]}}*</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" cols="4" rows="5"  name="comment" id="comment-textarea" tabindex="3" ng-model="commentText" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group button-group">
            <div class="control-field">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-comment" tabindex="4" >{{AdDetailsWords.commentPostLng[languageServ.current]}}*</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and the controller:

```
angular.module('mean.rank').controller('formController', function ($scope, OkianoData, CommentsService, $modalInstance, $modal, Global, items, $timeout, Languages) {
    var addDataToCurrntCommentList = {};
    var postCommentDataToServer = {};
    $scope.languageServ = Languages;
    console.log("OkianoData:",OkianoData)
    OkianoData.getAdDetailsWords().then(function(listWords) {
        console.log(listWords);
        $scope.AdDetailsWords = listWords;
    },function(reason) {
        alert(reason);
    });
    console.log("AdDetailsWords: ",$scope.AdDetailsWords);
    $scope.ad = items[0];
    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.selected = {
        item: $scope.items[0]
    };
    $scope.submitComment = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            postCommentDataToServer.nid = $scope.ad.nid;
            postCommentDataToServer.uid = Global.user.uid;
            postCommentDataToServer.posted = new Date();
            postCommentDataToServer.title = document.getElementById('commentTitle-textarea').value;
            postCommentDataToServer.text = document.getElementById('comment-textarea').value;
            //to current list
            //
            addDataToCurrntCommentList.author = Global.user._id;
            addDataToCurrntCommentList.posted = new Date();
            addDataToCurrntCommentList.title = document.getElementById('commentTitle-textarea').value;
            addDataToCurrntCommentList.text = document.getElementById('comment-textarea').value;
            //$scope.ad.comments.push((addDataToCurrntCommentList));
            CommentsService.postComment(postCommentDataToServer)
                .then(function () {
                        //console.log("adding : ", addDataToCurrntCommentList)
                    });

            $scope.finally();
    };
    $scope.finally = function(){
        $scope.commentTitle = "";
        $scope.commentText = "";
        $modalInstance.close('');

    }
    $scope.$watch('openAuto', function() {
        $scope.openAuto = false;
    });
    $scope.alertStar = function(val){
        addDataToCurrntCommentList.stars = val;
        postCommentDataToServer.stars = val;
        console.log("To server: ",postCommentDataToServer.stars);
        console.log("To list: ",addDataToCurrntCommentList.stars);
        for(var i=1;i<=val;i++)
        {
            document.getElementById(i).style.color='red';
        }
        for(var j=5;j>val;j--)
        {
            document.getElementById(j).style.color='';
        }

    };
});
```

Comment: The ng-repeat should render it if you add the items to the array. Perhaps you're adding it via JQuery ?

Comment: No jest a simple push.

Comment: Try doing `$scope.$apply();`

Comment: On? the comments array?

Comment: could you share the code surrounding the adding of the comment? Where do you get the comment from?

Comment: @weirdpanda You mean `$scope.$apply()`. Also, if he has to do it it means something's not written properly in the first place.

Comment: Could you please provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows your issue.

Comment: @OmriAharon, exactly. Just to debug that part, he can do a `$apply`. If it works out, there is something wrong with the wiring, if it doesn't, then there is some semantic fault.

Comment: Is your quantity updating?

Comment: $toskv - it is from $http request, I will edit it if needed but I want to add the comment as soon as the user add a comment.

Comment: when I re call the http request, the comment appears in the array(after ng-repeat).

Comment: ok, then please share the code in the modal you add the comment in. :)

Comment: I agree with @toskv, can you provide us with the code which does this?

Comment: Added the html+angular code. thank you, the submit comment function sends data to server.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas , it would be a little bit too obvious but could it be because the code that pushes the comment in the list is commented out? :D

Answer (score 0):

I have somewhat the same implementation and what I do is I have set up the loading of the data in a loadData function. Once the "push" of the comment is done (assuming via a $http.post), I just run the loadData() again.

Works for me and hope this helps (although now I see the date, it's two years old). Would be interesting to know how you tackled this.